# on using python to execute abstract shell code

Tags: python, shell, csv, command

I parsed some data that I put in a dictionary. Some of the dict values are updated with every read row.
I would like to input these dictionary elements using shellcode (it has to go an icinga cmd parser)

I'm a bit confused as to how to use os.popen if I want to execute this in shell :

/usr/bin/printf "[%lu] ADD_HOST_COMMENT;$1;1;CompuWare Ready;$2,$3\n" $now > $commandfile

the $1 $2 $3 will have to be replaced by dictionary values, $now needs to be existing date (not in my code yet).

maybe os.popen is not the way to go here

thx for your help & advice

---START---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# todo : test to see if provided argument or path does exist, else exit

#Script to use external commands
#Add Host Comment , can take up to 30s ! You can add multiple comments if you keep adding them !

#ADD_HOST_COMMENT;<hostname>,<persistent>,<author>;<comment>
#/bin/printf "[%lu] ADD_HOST_COMMENT;nagios.yourict.net;1;CompuWare Ready;This is a testcomment\n" $now >$commandfile


# where $1 is 1st argument : <hostname> as defined in icinga
# where $2 is 2nd argument : Service or app ie app_backup or app_newinfrastructure
# where $3 is 3nd argument : Location ie : loc_datacenter1 or loc_datacenter2\n

# now=`date +%s`
# commandfile='/omd/sites/master/tmp/run/icinga.cmd'
# /usr/bin/printf "[%lu] ADD_HOST_COMMENT;$1;1;CompuWare Ready;$2,$3\n" $now > $commandfile



from subprocess import call
import sys,os,csv


omd_site = 'master'
cmdfile = '/omd/sites/%s/tmp/run/icinga.cmd' % (omd_site)

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')              # open filename given as only argument
        csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')    # create a csv file object
        for row in csv_f:
                #dictionary containing our elements to use as comments field
                dict = {"hostname" : row[0], "group" : "grp_PDU", "service" : "svc_Datacenters", "location" : row[1]} 
                #filestrip = lines.strip()
                #print lines.strip()
                #print os.popen("printf " + filestrip).read()
                #print os.popen("printf " + dict["hostname"]).read() + os.popen("printf " + dict["group"]).read()
                os.popen("printf " + dict["group"]).read()
else:
        print "You did not provide exactly 1 argument. Exiting..."
        sys.exit
f.close()
```

---END---

Comment: did it like this, but doesn't seem to be working, but I found out how to parse python vars in call function whilst waiting for some community input
cmd = ["/usr/bin/printf", "\"[%lu] " + "ADD_HOST_COMMENT;" + str_host + ";1;" + str_group + ";" + str_svc + ",loc_" + str_loc + "\\\\n" + "\" " + str(unixtime) + " > " + ""]      
                call(cmd)

Comment: In the end I'm not going to execute this shell command because I need to write to a fifo, makes no sense what I'm doing... Will parse the data and write it to the fifo through python

Answer (score 0):

are you really need to post host comment with pipe ?
I think, best option is to put it into host config and reload icinga.